# TortoiseSVN - Checking out to multiple directories?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am very new to Tortoise and SVN's in general. I currently have a PHP project that I need to add to a SVN repository. I already had a checked out folder and i added the project to that folder and committed. So everything is cool.

But i just realized that I need to have the PHP project in my wamp folder's wwwroot to actually test it. I can copy and paste the folder to the wamp folder and then do the changes and replace the files back, but it is too cumbersome.

So what I want to do is actually checkout the same folder again from the repository to the wamp folder as well and keep working there and commit the changes which is MUCH easier!

Will this cause any trouble by having two copies? Is this is the correct way to handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't cause any problems, in fact this is exactly the sort of thing SVN is designed to handle! Just remember to update your www version if you commit changes to the other one, and vis versa.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, it will and that is the correct way

Answer (score 1):

You can keep as many SVN repository copies on your client machine as you want. However, if you plan on mainly working on the files in your wwwroot folder, I suggest you delete the other SVN folder to keep things simple. Otherwise you WILL at one point forget to syncronise the two, resulting in lost work and possibly long bughunts...

Answer (score 0):

Create a **link** ([`mklink`](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc753194%28WS.10%29.aspx) or [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx)) from your project folder to your WAMP folder. This way you don't need to checkout it twice.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I would say it won't cause any problem.

Since this is PHP project, your working code and the code on server will be same, except few configuration files.

However, considering development in general, it is better to give a build rather than directly synchronizing code from the repository into the live folder. For PHP projects, the build is very simple, simply copy entire folder to www directory. For projects, developed using other technologies, you may need to compile the code and make major changes to the settings.

Therefore, it is better to leave the code in the www folder as it is, and only update it with a build, rather than direct update from SVN repository.